# keras numpy error with load_img function

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

I am getting an error from the from keras.preprocessing.image.load_img function. Its saying an numpy object has no attribute 'load_img'. I'm not quite sure why its connecting this function in a keras module to an numpy object. Pretty new at python so maybe I'm missing something.

Below I have included a link to the picture of the error received. Your time and help is greatly appreciated.

[Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oxKME.png)

Comment: It seems that there is ‘image’ variable that hides ‘image’ module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, change the variable’s name from `image` to `img` for all use points. Then, restart the Python kernel and try your code again.

Comment: Awesome ty so much. Appreciate your time and help. Its working now =).

Comment: You’re welcome. And I would appreciate it if you can accept my post by clicking check mark.